# Inconsistent results in symbolic integration with Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, symbolic-math, integral

I'm encountering a problem with symbolic integration in Mathematica that is giving me inconsistent results even when using assumptions and clearing the variables.

```
$Assumptions = {t \[Element] Reals, 
   m \[Element] Reals, \[Sigma] \[Element] Reals, 
   p0 \[Element] Reals, a \[Element] Reals, g \[Element] Reals, 
   x \[Element] Reals};
$Assumptions = {t > 0, \[Sigma] > 0, g > 0, m > 0, a > 0, p0 > 0};

(*initial state*) \[Psi][x0_] = 
  1/(2 \[Pi] \[Sigma]^2)^(1/4)*Exp[-1/4*x0^2/\[Sigma]^2];
(*evolved state*)\[Psi]t[x_, t_] = (
  E^((m (-12 x^2 + 12 g t x (t - 4 I m \[Sigma]^2) + 
      g^2 t^3 (t - 8 I m \[Sigma]^2)))/(
   24 I t + 48 m \[Sigma]^2)) (2/\[Pi])^(1/4)
    Sqrt[-((I m)/(t \[Sigma]))])/Sqrt[-((2 I m)/t) + 1/\[Sigma]^2];

d\[Psi]g[x_, t_] = 
  D[\[Psi]t[x, t], g];

#now comes the problematic part
\[Alpha] =  
 Integrate[
  d\[Psi]gc[x, t]*d\[Psi]g[x, t], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

The expected result is `1/36 g^2 m^2 t^6 + t^4/(16 \[Sigma]^2) + m^2 t^2 \[Sigma]^2`. However, most of the time, I'm getting a very complicated and lengthy expression involving several GammaRegularized functions. Sometimes I do get the correct result, but it's inconsistent.

I have already tried the following approaches to address the issue:

1. Using the `Clear` function to clear the variables before each run.
2. Providing explicit assumptions for the variables involved in the integration, such as `t \[Element] Reals`.
3. Specifying specific ranges of values for the parameters involved in the integration, such as `m>0`, `g>0`, `a>0`, and `\sigma>0`.

Despite these attempts, I'm still facing inconsistent results.

Moreover, I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Mathematica but that didn't help. My professor sent me a notebook that performed some of the same calculations and he didn't have any problems on his PC, while I encountered the mentioned errors. He was using Mathematica 13.0, I'm using Mathematica 13.2.

Can anyone provide insights or suggestions on how to obtain consistent results in this symbolic integration problem? Is there any other approach or technique that can be used to improve the accuracy and consistency of the results? Or any setting I have to change?

Thank you in advance for your help.

---

Comment: While this is not necessarily off-topic here, you might get better answers posting here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com